# ¿Cómo hacer una navbar que cambie de color al bajar el scroll?

Tags: html, css

Tengo la siguiente navegación fija que al cargar el index esta con transparencia y solo muestra las secciones. Me gustaría que al bajar se pueda colorear esa navegación de blanco para que se pueda distinguir pero no logro hacerlo con css, mi código es el siguiente:

```
 nav

 <!-- Navbar Start -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-custom navbar-light sticky">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/logopatrosa2.png" height="100" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
            aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="mdi mdi-menu"></span>
        </button>
        <!--end button-->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-link mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <!--end nav item-->
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">Nosotros</a>
                </li>
                <!--end nav item-->

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Productos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="blondas.html">Blondas</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Item1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Item2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Item3</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Item4</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!--end nav item-->

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#news">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <!--end nav item-->
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contacto</a>
                </li>
                <!--end nav item-->
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 mt-2 mt-sm-0 social-icon light-social-icon">
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a onclick="location.href='://www.facebook.com/bmyfb/'"><i
                            class="mdi mdi-facebook"></i></a></li>

                <li class="list-inline-item"><a onclick="location.href='https://www.instagram.com/myinsta/'"><i
                            class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end container-->
</nav>
<!-- Navbar End -->
```

CSS

```
.navbar-custom {
 padding: 20px 0;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 0px;
 z-index: 999;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler {
 color: #272727;
 font-size: 30px;
 padding: 0px;
 }

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
 margin-right: 0 !important;
 }

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .l-dark {
 display: none;
 }

 .navbar-custom .navbar-brand .l-light {
 display: inline-block;
 }

 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 13px;
 background-color: transparent !important;
 margin: 0 8px;
 font-weight: 500;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 line-height: 24px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 transition: all 0.5s;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
 }

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover, .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:active {
 color: #c52c20;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link {
color: #c52c20 !important;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav.navbar-nav-link .nav-item .nav-link {
 color: #272727;
 }

 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav.navbar-nav-link .nav-item .nav-link:hover, 
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav.navbar-nav-link .nav-item .nav-link:active {
 color: #c52c20;
 }

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav.navbar-nav-link.active .nav-link {
 color: #c52c20 !important;
 }
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-item:last-child .nav-link {
 margin-right: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
 }

.navbar-custom .social-icon {
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
 }

.navbar-custom .social-icon li a {
 color: #272727;
 border-color: #272727;
 }

.navbar-custom .social-icon.light-social-icon li a {
 color: #e9ecef;
border-color: #e9ecef;
}

.nav-sticky.navbar-custom {
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 12px 0px;
background-color: #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 33px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      box-shadow: 0 10px 33px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
color: #272727 !important;
}

.nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
 margin-right: 0 !important;
 }

.nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .l-dark {
  display: inline-block;
  }

.nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .l-light {
 display: none;
 }

 .nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
margin-top: 0px;
 }

 .nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #2f3545 !important;
 }

 .nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover, .nav- 
 sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:active {
 color: #c52c20 !important;
}

 .nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link {
 color: #c52c20 !important;
 }

.nav-sticky.navbar-custom.sticky-light {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 }

 .nav-sticky .navbar-brand {
  color: #272727 !important;
 }

 .nav-sticky .social-icon.light-social-icon li a {
  color: #272727;
  border-color: #272727;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr mediante 2 elementos

- Evento `scroll` mediante un *listener* al objeto `document`
- Recuperamos un una variable el scroll sobre el [eje Y o vertical](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) al objeto window
- El uso de `scrollY`nos regresa la cantidad de pixeles que nos desplazamos por lo tanto con una estructura de condicionales podemos solventar escribiendo rangos de los mismos para modificar el color agregando una clase con un `background-color` específico

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        .color-rojo {
          background-color: red;
          height: 1600px;
        }
        .color-verde {
          background-color: green;
          height: 1600px;
        }
        .contenedor-menu__contenedor {
          height: 1600px;
        }
        .color-amarillo {
          height: 1600px;
          background-color: yellow;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <main class="contenedor-menu">
      <nav class="contenedor-menu__contenedor">
        Menú de navegación
      </nav>
    </main>
    <script>
      class Color {
        constructor(lienzo, scrollAbajo) {
          this.lienzo = lienzo
          this.scrollAbajo = scrollAbajo
        }
        
        cambiaColor() {
          document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
          let scrollAbajo = window.scrollY;
          (scrollAbajo >= 0 && scrollAbajo <= 500) ? this.lienzo.setAttribute("class", "color-rojo")
          : (scrollAbajo > 500 && scrollAbajo <= 1000) ? this.lienzo.setAttribute("class", "color-verde")
          : this.lienzo.setAttribute("class", "color-amarillo")
          })
        }
      }
      let lienzo = document.querySelector(".contenedor-menu__contenedor")
      let scrollAbajo = window.scrollY
      const color = new Color(lienzo, scrollAbajo)
      color.cambiaColor()
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```